# $S$ is any non empty set and $2^S$ is the power set of $S$. True or False for the following

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$S$ is any non empty set and $2^S$ is the power set of $S$.

let $S = \{ 1,2 \}$. Then the power set $P(S) = \{\{1,2\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \emptyset \}$ where P(S) contains $2^2=4$ elements.

True or False for

1. $S \in 2^S$ True as S is in the power set S
2. $S\subset 2^S$ True as every element of S is in P(S)
3. $\{S\}\in 2^S$
4. $\{S\} \subset 2^S$

Not sure how to answer the remainder...

Comment: The second statement is not true, since the elements of $P(S)$ do not contain the elements of $S$, but **the sets formed by elements of $S$**. For example, $a \in S$, then $\{ a \} \in P(S)$ but **not** $a \in P(S)$. Same reasons for the failure of the third and fourth statement.

Comment: Use `\{` and `\}` to get $\{$ and $\}$ when using MathJax. And `\emptyset` to get $\emptyset$.

Comment: 2. is False. $1 \in S$ but $1 \not \in P(S)$

Comment: You should make up your mind for ONE notation, using sometimes $2^S$ and sometimes $P(S)$ is strictly correct, but distracting.

Answer (score 1):

For 3:

$\{S\} \in 2^S$?

Let's see:

Is $\{S\} = \{\{1,2\}\}$ an element of $2^S = \{\{1,2\},\{1\},\{2\},\emptyset\}$?

$\{\{1,2\}\} \ne \{1,2\}$

$\{\{1,2\}\} \ne \{1\}$

$\{\{1,2\}\} \ne \{2\}$

$\{\{1,2\}\} \ne \emptyset$

So no, $\{S\}$ is not an element of $2^S$.

Comment: @Zerox: $\{S\} = \{\{1,2\}\}$ This would imply that $ 4) \{S\} \subset 2^S$ is true because every element of $\{\}$ is in $2^S$?

Comment: @shoggananna Yes, your understanding is correct.